# time of change and convert to datetime

Tags: c#, .net, perforce

I have to select `changelists` from perforce the problem is when I extracted information but the problem is that the date  and the time look not significative so how can I change this string to significative date and time

example of result 1361898522

the code:

```
P4Command cm1 = new P4Command(ps, "changes", true, String.Format("{0}", deppath1));
Options opchanges = new Options();
opchanges.Add(op1,op2);
P4CommandResult results1 = cm1.Run(opchanges);
TaggedObjectList listfiledown1 = new TaggedObjectList();
listfiledown1 = (results1.TaggedOutput);

foreach (TaggedObject obj in listfiledown1)
{      
     foreach (String s in obj.Keys)
     {
         String value = "n/a";
         obj.TryGetValue(s, out value);
         var changeList = value.Split ('@');       
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "significative"? What is the expected date and time of the value 1361898522?

Comment: can we change that to YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM

Comment: and about the expected result that what i am lookin for

Comment: Please, provide us the code which actually works with dateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* the value 1361898522 is meant to be Tue, 26 Feb 2013 17:08:42 UTC, then it looks like this is a Unix timestamp - a number of seconds since the Unix epoch. This is easy to do in C#:

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                                                          DateTimeKind.Utc);

...

public static DateTime FromUnixTimestamp(long seconds)
{
    return UnixEpoch + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
}
```

Note the UTC `DateTimeKind` so that the epoch is appropriately UTC rather than in the system local time zone.

Using my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project it's even easier, as of version 1.1:

```
Instant timestamp = Instant.FromSecondsSinceUnixEpoch(seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the date time values are expressed in Unix time: the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

For example, if you write:

```
        var epoc = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01);
        dt = epoc + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1361898522);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

The result is:

```
2013/02/26 17:08:42
```